# Assigning value to string variable

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I'm trying to parse an xml file for the value of an element and then assign that single value to a variable. I understand that I can do this:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("filename");
string someName;  
var name = from n in xdoc.Descendants("name")
           select (string)n;

foreach(var n in name )
{
   someName = n;
}
```

My question is how can I do the same thing, but without a foreach loop?

Comment: Can you clarify what is expected output? E.g. you have three `name` elements in your xml with values Bob, John and Mike

Comment: It is stated in the question that there is a single name element, not three.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string someName = (string)xdoc.Descendants("name").First();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have single `name` element in your xml file, then either use @abatishchev solution (probably with `FirstOrDefault` instead of `First` if element can be missing) or you can use XPath query:

```
string someName = (string)xdoc.XPathSelectElement("//name");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know there is only a single element in `name`, you can do it like this:

```
someName = name.Single();
```